# Vagrant docker provisioning with env variables and network

Tags: docker, vagrant

I have a docker image, which I wish to run inside vagrant. The manual run command looks like this :

```
docker run  --name container1 --network=host  -p 1111:9990  -e "USER=dummy" -e "PASS=P$SSW0RD" image_name paramToEntrypoint
```

How can I translate it to the vagrant docker provisioner? 
To be more specific, I am not sure:

- How to specify the host
- How to pass env variables to docker
- How to pass parameter to dockers entrypoint

Comment: Not an answer, but I recommend using docker compose. You define the containers in a yaml file, and just point docker-compose at it to bring the containers up (`docker-compose up`). There is also a docker-compose provisioner plugin for vagrant, again, where you just define the yaml file to bring up.

Comment: Sure. My problem is I cannot run it locally on Mac due to host network complications, hence the vagrant :)